# Silverstripe TEMP_FOLDER differs by fpm and cli

Tags: php, nginx, silverstripe

We have a lot of silverstripe installations - each on its own vServer.
Deployment is done by a deployment service.
Each instance is powered by `nginx` and `php5.6-fpm`.

When a deployment is running, the typical `build/flush` actions are executed by the deployment service as ssh commands.

The `cli` tasks are run by the same user like `php5.6-fpm` is running.

But the php-Versions are not identical (`fpm+cli`)

This results in 2 different cache directories

```
/tmp/silverstripe-cache-php5.6.23... (fpm)
```

and

```
/tmp/silverstripe-cache-php5.6.29... (cli)
```

This is really bad. Example:
There is a new static class variable, that is stored inside the `ConfigManifest`.
But it is only stored in the manifest of the cache directory that matches the cli version.

The worst case: When browsing the website (`php5.6-fpm` usage) this config variable is not known. This can lead to `server errors (500)`, because the manifest of the fpm does not know about the new config class variable.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Kind regards, Robert

Comment: make sure cli and fpm have the same user and php version.

Comment: @wmk - this would be a a hard task

Comment: why? You have both installed on the machine and you can use `sudo`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to mix slightly different php versions is to use temp folder in the root of the project.

1. create `silverstripe-cache` folder in the project root folder
2. add `putenv('APACHE_RUN_USER=php-fpm');` in your `_ss_environment.php` file to force the name of the cache folder to be 'php-fpm'
3. it is system configuration to ensure write access to the 'silverstripe-cache/php-fpm' folder from php-fpm and cli.

See framework\core\TempPath.php for the logic.